# .env value is not read from the outer folder in Node js

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, dotenv

I have a folder structure

```
 - iNotebook 
    - Backend
        - Routes 
        - Config.js 
        - .env
    - Public
    - src
```

Backend folder has node and empress project
public and src folder are for react
In the backend folder I have config.js having code

```
require('dotenv').config();

module.exports = {JWT_SECRET:process.env.JWT_SECRET};
```

In Routes I use `config.JWT_SECRET` and use thunderclient in vs code to get the response.
When I am inside Backend folder and send the request by thunderclient, my code works.
but if I open the iNotebook folder and send the request by thunderclient from that folder, then i get the error `config.JWT_SECRET` value is undefined.

Why the value from env can only be recevied if it is directly present in the folder I am working on, and not on the outer folder.

Comment: try with `require(__dirname + '/dotenv').config();`

Comment: @DhavalDarji Thanks, it does not work but I got an idea and ```require('dotenv').config({path:__dirname+'/.env'});``` this works